# export default class extends Vue not reachable from template

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I started with Vue.js in combination with typescript and somehow I can't read out my values from outside the class.

```
@Component({
    name: 'SidebarItem',
    components: {
      SidebarItemLink
    }
  })

export default class extends Vue {
 get someValue(){
   return 1234
 }
}
```

so when I try to get the someValue() to display, it gives a unresolved variable error

```
<template>
<div>
<p>{{some value}}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create a simple minimal solution for your problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-simple-getvalue)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
@Component({
  components: {},
  template: `
    <div>      
      <template>
        <div>
        <p>{{someValue}}</p>
        </div>
        </template>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App extends Vue {
  count = 0;
  onButtonClicked(val) {
    this.count++;
  }
  get someValue() {
    return 12345
  }
}
```